# Facebook - Cannot post to a user who has not installed the application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("name", "ABC");
params.putString("link", "http://www.example.com/");
params.putString("to", "1015787142");

    WebDialog feedDialog = (
           new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
                Session.getActiveSession(), params))
                .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                            FacebookException error) {
                        //...
                          ...
                    }}).build();
    feedDialog.show();
```

But I am getting this exception when posting to friend's wall. Can anyone please help me to get rid of this.

```
 {FacebookServiceException: httpResponseCode: -1, facebookErrorCode: 100, facebookErrorType: null, message: Cannot post to a user who has not installed the application.}
```

**Note: Posting to my wall is working fine. Its the friend's wall that is bugging me

Answer (score 1):

You can´t post to a friends wall, even if he would have installed your App. Facebook removed this oppertunity a long time ago, because it would always be spam - ESPECIALLY if the friend did not install the App.

Edit: There is one way to post to a friend's profile, but only through the feed dialog, and that friend must also be using your app. See developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.2, specifically the "to" field. (Thanx to Ming Li for the additional information)

Comment: It used work previously, I am getting this error since 2 days

Comment: impossible, you just can´t post to a friends wall. if it was possible in your app somehow, then you should file a bug. no app should be able to post to a friends wall and that´s not even an api version thing.

Comment: You can post to a friend's profile, but only through the feed dialog, and that friend must also be using your app. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.2, specifically the "to" field.

Comment: thanx for the heads up, i will add it to my answer - although, i believe vicky wanted to post without a dialog - which is not a good idea anyway ;)